# Why does "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" lock a table?

Tags: mysql

We recently run into "waiting for table metadata lock" issues, after  "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" has been fired several hundred times per second.

This is not a request for help (obviously we refactored that code), but I try to understand why that command locks table metadata. It was my understanding that this would be a read-only operation if the table indeed does exist.

Server version: 10.1.37-MariaDB-0+deb9u1 Debian 9.6

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The locks in mysql are un-necessarily restrictive before it even checks if the table already exists.  The bug report, that seems to be being ignored by mysql but has been fixed on a fork of mysql, explains it pretty well:

> If one session had any metadata lock on a table, another session
>   attempting CREATE TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] for the same table would 
>   hang. This occurred due to an attempt in the second session to
>   acquire an exclusive metadata lock on the table before checking
>   whether the table already existed. An exclusive metadata lock is not
>   compatible with any other metadata locks, so the session hung for the
>   lock timeout period if another session had the table locked.

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=63144

The fork that fixed it by using the (rather obvious) solution of doing a shared lock to see if it exists, then if it did not exist upgrading to an exclusive lock.

Answer (score 1):

It could be as innocent as avoiding creating two tables with the same name.